# Issues with display scaling on second monitor

Tags: linux-mint, display, cinnamon

I have laptop running Linux mint cinnamon which I am trying use with a portable second monitor. The laptop screen is 3840x2160 and the second display is 2560x1600 I am using linux mints in-built "Display" utility with fractional screen controls enabled (if not both screens are locked to the same scaling).

I have the laptop screen set to 200% display scaling and would like to set the portable monitor to either 125% or 150% scaling.

If I set the second display to anything other than 200% scaling the display only shows the top left of the desktop (i.e. the portable monitor is showing a desktop which the physical size of a 20-27" screen however as it is only 16" I am seeing only the top-left portion of it).

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This should/could work.

Use `xrandr` in your `.xinitrc`, should be something like:

`xrandr --output <name_of_primary_display> --primary --mode 3840x2160 --rate <display_refresh_rate> --scale 2x2 --output <second_display> --mode 2560x1600 --rate <display_refresh_rate> --scale 1.25x1.25 --right-of <name_of_primary_display>`

Use the flags `--right-of` or `--left-of` to set the position of the display.

To retrieve the information information needed, do `xrandr -q`.

Before putting that command in `.xinitrc`, try using it directly from the command line.

Comment: I tried the command you suggested. However, for some reason it set the scale of the primary display to 100% and the secondary display was again only showing the top left of the desktop

Comment: Look at the answer from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596887/how-to-scale-the-resolution-display-of-the-desktop-and-or-applications), it has all the info you need to make it work, especially the part of the second screen. It seems the problem lays in the discrepancy between scaling and resolution.