How to change Xorg screen resolution on Surface Pro?
I have a Surface Pro, Gen. 5 with Debian installed. When I open X, everything is so tiny, I cannot read text. Its as if the writing is 2px high. Windows similarly are really tiny, with a terminal window being just 2" at 80 characters wide.
I tried this command: xrandr --fb 1280x1024. Instead of resizing the display, it made it so I can only use the top left 1/3 corner of the screen. The moouse and windows cannot enter the right 2/3 nor bottom 2/3 of the screen.
How do I adjust the screen resolution?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596887/how-to-scale-the-resolution-display-of-the-desktop-and-or-applications
