# How do I debug this issue about making xrandr permanent?

Tags: debian, x11, xrandr, troubleshooting

I'm trying to change my screen resolution at startup using xrandr.

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493851/355594), I symlinked a script as `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45setoutput`. Here's the content of script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xrandr --newmode "1600x900" 118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1600x900"
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1600x900"
```

After login I see the screen flashing as if the script is running but then it shows the usual resolution. It's weird since when I run `xrandr -q` I do see 1600x900 as an available mode and if I run `xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1600x900"` it then works.

Comment: What happened when you ran the script interactively after login: `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45setoutput`?

Comment: It just works as it's supposed to

Comment: Don't expect people to read the comments. Put edits in the question.